# Set the number formatting in general for a Highcharts chart?

Tags: highcharts

I've been looking all over, and testing one million things now. I just can't get it to work. I want the numbers to show up as "99 999" instead of "99,999".

Yes, I eventually found "thousandsSep", but it seems to be ignored completely. All my numbers show up as "99,999" even when I have "lang: { thousandsSep: ' ' }" and whatnot.

Please help.

Comment: Do you have source code?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by that. This is just a question of where/how this option is supposed to be set...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thousandsSep works for me:

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            thousandsSep: ' '
        }
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled : true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [10029, 1715, 1006, 1292, 14400, 1760, 135, 1480, 10216, 1194, 1956, 1544]        
        }]
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FPF2t/

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I had missed that you need a special "setOptions" thing; I had it right in the main definition of the chart. (In fact, I see nothing that indicates that this would be needed/logical. I always get stuck like this when trying to use libraries.)